# Discripencies in variable importance calculation for glmnet model in R

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet, vip

I want to calculate variable importance for glmnet model in R. I am using `glmnet` package for fitting the elastic net model like

```
library(glmnet)
library(caret)
library(vip)

data_y <- as.vector(mtcars$mpg)
data_x <- as.matrix(mtcars[-1])

fit.glmnet <- glmnet(data_x, data_y, family="gaussian")

set.seed(123)
cvfit.glmnet = cv.glmnet(data_x, data_y, standardize=T)
cvfit.glmnet$lambda.min
coef(cvfit.glmnet, s = "lambda.min")
```

Then I have used `vip` package for variable importance as

```
#Using vip package
vip::vi_model(cvfit.glmnet, s = cvfit.glmnet$fit$lambda)
```

which returns me

```
># A tibble: 10 x 3
   Variable Importance Sign 
   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>
 1 cyl         -0.886  NEG  
 2 disp         0      NEG  
 3 hp          -0.0117 NEG  
 4 drat         0      NEG  
 5 wt          -2.71   NEG  
 6 qsec         0      NEG  
 7 vs           0      NEG  
 8 am           0      NEG  
 9 gear         0      NEG  
10 carb         0      NEG
```

The variable importance contains both positive and negative values for the variables at the same time it does not vary between 0-1 or 0-100%.

Then I have tried customised function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641109/6123824)

```
#Using function provided in this example
varImp <- function(object, lambda = NULL, ...) {
  
  ## skipping a few lines
  
  beta <- predict(object, s = lambda, type = "coef")
  if(is.list(beta)) {
    out <- do.call("cbind", lapply(beta, function(x) x[,1]))
    out <- as.data.frame(out)
  } else out <- data.frame(Overall = beta[,1])
  out <- abs(out[rownames(out) != "(Intercept)",,drop = FALSE])
  out
}

varImp(cvfit.glmnet, lambda = cvfit.glmnet$lambda.min)
```

It returns me following output

```
        Overall
cyl  0.88608541
disp 0.00000000
hp   0.01168438
drat 0.00000000
wt   2.70814703
qsec 0.00000000
vs   0.00000000
am   0.00000000
gear 0.00000000
carb 0.00000000
```

Though the output from customised function does not contain negative values, it does vary within 0-1 or 0-100%.

I know that `caret` package has `varImp`function which gives variable importance between 0-100%. But I want to implement the same thing for `cv.glmnet` object instead of `caret::train` object. How can I achieve the variable importance alike `caret` package for `cv.glmnet` object?

Comment: What would you say are variables more important if they have a higher coefficient at a certain lambda or if their coefficient reaches 0 at higher L1 penalty?

Comment: I think the variables which are having a higher coefficient at a certain lambda, are more important.

Comment: Why did you not call `vip::vi_model(cvfit.glmnet, s = cvfit.glmnet$lambda.min)`? as in the call `varImp(cvfit.glmnet, lambda = cvfit.glmnet$lambda.min)`. I get the same values with the difference `varImp` returns the absolute values of the coefficients.

Comment: Even after using `vip::vi_model(cvfit.glmnet, s = cvfit.glmnet$lambda.min)`, I am getting different results only.

Comment: Could you update the question with the results you are getting?

Comment: I have updated the question with the results I am getting.

Comment: These are the same results, only the `vip::vi_model` are rounded at three digits while the absolute values of coefficients is given by `varImp`

Comment: Ooo yes, those are same only. But how can I achieve the variable importance alike `caret` package for `cv.glmnet` object i.e. 0-100 or 0-1?

Comment: just rescale the `varImp` to 0-1. This can be achieved by dividing by the maximum.

Comment: It will be great if you can modify the code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks how to obtain glmnet variable importance between 0-100%.

If it is desired to assign importance based on coefficient magnitude at a certain (usually optimal) penalty. And if these coefficients are derived based on standardized variables (default in glmnet) then the coefficients can simply be scaled to the 0 - 1 range:

The slightly modified function is given:

```
varImp <- function(object, lambda = NULL, ...) {
  beta <- predict(object, s = lambda, type = "coef")
  if(is.list(beta)) {
    out <- do.call("cbind", lapply(beta, function(x) x[,1]))
    out <- as.data.frame(out)
  } else out <- data.frame(Overall = beta[,1])
  out <- abs(out[rownames(out) != "(Intercept)",,drop = FALSE])
  out <- out/max(out)
  out[order(out$Overall, decreasing = TRUE),,drop=FALSE]
}
```

Using the example in the question:

```
varImp(cvfit.glmnet, lambda = cvfit.glmnet$lambda.min)
#output
         Overall
wt   1.000000000
cyl  0.320796270
am   0.004840186
hp   0.004605913
disp 0.000000000
drat 0.000000000
qsec 0.000000000
vs   0.000000000
gear 0.000000000
carb 0.000000000
```

Another approach at assigning variable importance to glmnet models would be scoring the variables based on the penalty for inclusion - Variables are more significant if the are excluded at higher penalties. This approach will be implemented in the mlr3 package: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3learners/issues/28 at some point

Comment: Thank you very, can you provide the other approach you have mentioned using `mlr3` package?

Comment: It looks I was mistaken and it is yet to be implemented: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3learners/issues/28

Comment: Ok, the function `varImp` is basically taken from `caret` package. While we implement it using `caret` package, we get the scaled importance but when it is used as mentioned in my question, it does not provide the scaled importance. Can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: It appears that there is an additional processing of the output from the varImp function where it is scaled to 0 - 1 range for all learners that have importance slots in caret. Consider these examples: `caret::varImp(test_class_cv_model, lambda = 0.007)` and 
`caret::varImp(test_class_cv_model$finalModel, lambda = 0.007)` If you call it on the gimlet model you get unscaled importance while if you call in on the train object you get scaled importance. You can check what happens additionally in the call on the train object via `caret:::varImp.train`